# Why aren't cutebolds the dominant race in a setting with firearms?

Tags: science-based, biology, firearms, modern

So, cutebolds are small (85 cm tall) humanoid creatures, covered in fine (usually gray) scales with a theorized taxonomical connection to dragons, which shows in their long lifespans. They breed slower than humans, but the population is still roughly the same.

[image]
*Most depictions of cutebolds are usually rather cartoonish, since almost all of them were drawn by cutebold children.*

They have everything for modern warfare. They have human intelligence, are much better at sneaking, can use more things as cover. Though limited to weaker firearms, they can still use fixed turrets. Plus, they have David Bowie who had come back as a lich, as their king, not to mention that they're cute.

Yet, humans are still the dominant species up until the (You should probably skip this paragraph) naruto-running titan zombies show up and tear the human empires to shreds.

Cutebolds had no homeland on the surface (despite being perfectly adapted to living in the sunlight) during the rule of human empires and had to live underground. As far as history goes, they started out just as well as human (with the ancient tech and all that fun stuff), yet they never actually fought humans and just submitted to them for some reason.

It's clear cutebolds have little problem traversing narrow caverns, but they also hate being there 24/7, So why would cutebolds just give up fighting when they have a reason and will (and since they were just as good technologically (guns), and in terms of numbers) and power to oppose humans? **My guess is the reason is in some physiological limitation, but what could that be?**

Comment: You said it: They don't breed as fast. Any conflict with prolonged attrition will put humans at a very clear advantage.

Comment: At what era the conflict with humans took place? Did they have weapons and population parity back then?

Comment: I vote in agreement with the "opinion-based" close votes. Some opinions/ideas that I might venture, however: maybe they're just not warlike? You know: sane. Maybe, being cute, humans treat them nicely, and they don't feel stirred to war? Maybe they, like elephants, see us as cute? Maybe they're predisposed to be obedient to those larger than them? So many possibilities, sadly.

Comment: Also, given David Bowie is their immortal <strike>god</strike> king, they presumably see humans as objects of worship or awe

Comment: Why would their *firearms* be weaker than ours, per se?

Comment: @Shalvenay 'cause they're smaller, though that limitation only applies to handheld weapons.

Comment: @Mephistopheles -- are we talking blackpowder-era firearms, or modern smokeless/cartridge stuff?

Comment: @Shalvenay Smokeless.

Comment: @Mephistopheles -- how much smaller were you thinking?  because I'd think they'd be the masters of cramming a lot of firearm, so to speak, in a small space (i.e. instead of wielding .22 pocketguns, they'd be rocking subcompact 9mms, and designing their rifle systems for carbines instead of full-length rifles)

Comment: @Shalvenay I'm not sure. I think they could use normal human pistols (something like a glock and not monstrosities like a .50 BMG handcannon)

Answer (score 3):

They reproduce slower, so long wars would be devastating. Sneaking is pretty useless with modern technology. Their weapons might not be good enough, especially when you consider that human guns don't always kill, and that humans are actually a very resilient animal. I see that they are tetrapods from the picture, and if they're related to dragons they are probably reptiles. Humans are more adaptable (I'm pretty sure). Humans would probably have better defenses of they had better weapons, which they apparently do (You said weaker firearms). With all this to consider, humans would probably win, and they would probably refrain from attacking a species that appears so much scarier. They might be too busy trying to survive, they're probably having a bad time because there aren't even enough resources for all of the humans.

I guess this doesn't matter but personally I doubt that they would reach our level of intelligence and our numbers. Being reptiles, they would have trouble surviving the way early humans did because of lower dexterity and an inability to use persuit predation, which is one of the only reasons humans are viable.

I don't know anything about this world you are referencing, so I could be completely wrong about everything.